# accumulate async updates into single observable

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

In my component i have observable array of items

`items: Observable<Item[]>;`

Also in my service ItemProvider i have a method which returns new updates.

`ItemProvider.getUpdates() : Observable<Item[]> {...};`

I'd like to append result of the `getUpdates()` into `items`.

First items is empty

```
items = []

method getUpdates() is called and returns array [item1, item2, item3]

we add these items into items array
items = [item1, item2, item3]

method getUpdates() is called and returns array [item4, item5]

we add these items into items array
items = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]
```

Comment: what have you tried? Or are you expecting us to do it for you?

Comment: @MikeTung Oh boy ... no i don't. I am just not experienced with Rxjs nor typescript. According to the doc there are plenty of various object i can use hot/cold observables (vanilla,Subject, ReplaySubject, BehaviourSubject). Not sure what is the best match.

Answer (score 0):

When you are wanting to combine existing observables there are a range of different operators you can use, eg. concat, merge, combineLatest, withLatest from. It is usually best to use these to combine two observables into one rather then using Subjects.

In the example you give, where you are wanting to append one observable to another the concat operator is the obvious option, eg.

```
let items = Observable.from([0]);

const updates = Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);

items = items.pipe(concat(updates));

items.subscribe(item => console.log(item)) // 0,1,2,3

const updates2 = Observable.from([4, 5, 6]);

items = items.pipe(concat(updates2));

items.subscribe(item => console.log(item)) // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

For the concat operator to work though the observables being combined need to complete. If they don't complete then you could try the merge operator, but in this case you can't guarantee the order in which they are combined.